# xml tree remove elements

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to remove elements from my tree based on the elements attributes.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import requests

xml = requests.get("https://iptv-org.github.io/epg/guides/ca/sportsnet.ca.epg.xml").text
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml))
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in tree.iter():
    if elem.tag == "channel" or elem.tag == "programme":
        if elem.attrib.get("id", "") == "WWENetworkCanada.us" or elem.attrib.get("channel", "") == "WWENetworkCanada.us":
            pass
        else:
            print("removing")
            root.remove(elem)

ET.dump(root)
```

The dump still has the elements I am trying to remove, even though I see "removing". Can anyone see why?

I am expecting everything that is not "WWENetworkCanada.us" to be removed.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Since you haven't shared what `my condition` and `another condition` are, nor the data being used in those conditions, we can't tell if your code actually reaches `root.remove(elem)`.  You will need to provide a lot more detail, and explain how you have _proved_ to yourself (and us) that the `remove` is actually being executed.

Comment: Sorry. Yes the conditions work. I used print statements to confirm.

Comment: OK I have added an actual example

Comment: Now add the input XML and output.  Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: I figured it out. Its because I forgot to do `for elem in list(tree.iter()):`. I was changing indexes as I looped previously.

Answer (score 1):

It was failing because I was changing indexes as I iterating and removing. What I needed to do was `for elem in list(tree.iter()):`. This is something I learnt some time ago (on here) that lets you remove while iterating without creating a "temp" list.

Answer (score 1):

Saw you answered your own question, but thought I'd share as an alternate approach. Simply use `findall()` to find and remove any values that don't match what you are looking for

### Remove Unwanted Elements using findall()

```
for elem in tree.findall("./channel/[@id!='WWENetworkCanada.us']"):
    root.remove(elem)
    
for elem in tree.findall("./programme/[@channel!='WWENetworkCanada.us']"):
    root.remove(elem)
```